# What is the easiest way to test event listeners in jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, jestjs, event-listener

I'm trying to test the below function

```
 getVal(process) {
    test.on('data', async data => {
    try {
       for (const val of data) {
       await process(val);
       console.log('processed')
    }} catch (e) {}
    });
    test.on('error', err => {
       console.log('error', err)
     });
    }

process(payload) {
return new Promise(resolve=>{.....})
};
```

Jest test: 
// in beforeEach

```
mockData =[an array containing 10 values] 
    onSpy = jest
          .fn()
          .mockImplementationOnce(async (data, callback) => {
            callback(mockData);
          })
          .mockImplementationOnce((error, callback) => {
            callback(mockErr);
          });

 it('should trigger callback once per message', async () => {
    await xyz.getVal(process);
    await expect(process).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(10);
 });
```

I expect the `process()` to be called 10 times since the data is sent 10 times. However it's called only 2 times when I assert but when I put a console.log in the function itself and run the test, that gets called 10 times.

I'm not sure what's wrong. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that calling `await` on `xyz.getVal` doesn't actually do anything since `getVal` is a synchronous function that just sets up the event listeners...

...so the asynchronous events haven't finished processing by the time the `expect` runs and fails.

---

It looks like you've already got a spy on `test.on`.

Instead of mocking its implementation, just use it to get the callback function.

Then you can call and `await` the callback function directly:

```
  // in beforeEach
  mockData = [an array containing 10 values]
  onSpy = jest.fn();

it('should trigger callback once per message', async () => {
  xyz.getVal(process);
  const callback = onSpy.mock.calls[0][1];  // <= get the callback (second argument of the first call to test.on)
  await callback(mockData);  // <= call and await the callback directly
  expect(process).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(10);  // Success!
});
```

Comment: I see TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined with the above

Comment: You need a spy for `test.on`...then `.mock.calls[0][1]` will be your callback function.  @user2821242

Comment: If you update your question with more of your code (show how `test` gets imported into your code file) I can create a more complete answer if it's helpful.  @user2821242

Comment: Actually what you suggested worked. My bad. How do I do that for 'error' ? if you check above it has test.on('data'...) and test.on('error'). Also though this worked, I'm a bit confused how . I'm not 100% clear why onSpy.mock.calls[0][1]. Can you explain a bit more? I have updated the above with the actual process()

Comment: The `error` callback will be the second argument of the second call to `test.on`, so you can get it from your spy with `.mock.calls[1][1]` @user2821242

Comment: [`.mock.calls`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockcalls) provides "an array containing the call arguments of all calls that have been made to this mock function" @user2821242